# weighted data in hypothesis test

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I want to measure what is the chance my `WeightedData` follows uniform distribution? I am trying the following. But can't get the hypothesis test function to accept the `WeightedData` construct.

```
PearsonChiSquareTest[weightedData,
  UniformDistribution[{3.5099136*^9, 3.6762336*^9}]]
```

It works if i provide the data explicitly but the data is too big. Also is there a way to explicitly display `WeightedData`?

Comment: can you provide the data?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, you can use this data, `weightedData=WeightedData[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {10, 200, 30, 10}]`.

Comment: When describing a problem it really helps if you give all relevant information such as the error message.  The error message one gets is "PearsonChiSquareTest::rctnln: The argument WeightedData[Automatic,{{1,2,3,4},{10,200,30,10}}] at position 1 should be a rectangular array of real numbers with length greater than the dimension of the array."  It would seem that `PearsonChiSquareTest` doesn't accept a `WeightedData` object.  You could construct the equivalent test using `HistogramList`.

Comment: A sample size of 10^8 takes about 30 seconds to return a P-value from `PearsonChiSquareTest`.  How many samples to you have?

Comment: I have around 73 million records but the problem is fitting it into memory. But in Weighted form it is around 7 million with a column for frequency.

Comment: Is there a way for mathematica functions to accept `WeightedData`. I mean whats the point for having this construct if there is no way to use it in other function while mathematica claims to be very integrated.